# How to access a atribute in a different class

Tags: c++, oop

I'm doing a program that just have to print value of the variables, i think the first class is working, the 'm_valor' is printed like i want , but the second class should be printing 'm_valor + m_valorAdicional', but it is printing just the value of 'm_valorAdicional':

```
#ifndef INGRESSO_H
#define INGRESSO_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ingresso
{
protected:
    float m_valor;
public:
    Ingresso(): m_valor(0){};
    Ingresso(float valor): m_valor(valor){};
    ~Ingresso(){};
    float getValor() const {return m_valor; };
    
};

class IngressoVip : public Ingresso
{
private:
    float m_valorAdicional;

public:
    IngressoVip(): m_valorAdicional(0){};
    IngressoVip(float valor): m_valorAdicional(valor){};
    ~IngressoVip(){};
    float getValor(){return m_valorAdicional +=m_valor;};
};

#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "Ingresso.hpp"

int main()
{
    Ingresso a(10);
    IngressoVip b(5);
    out<<"valor Ingresso: "<<a.getValor()<<endl;
    cout<<"valor IngressoVip: "<<b.getValor()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I think this should be easy, but i just don't know what i have to do  to work like i want.

Comment: `b` is not `a`. The second class is actually printing `m_valor + m_valorAdicional` where `m_valor` is zero.

Comment: You should just use `+` instead of `+=` here `return m_valorAdicional +=m_valor;` Also for that to return something more meaninful, you'd have to have a constructor or setters that allow you to set both `m_valorAdicional` and `m_valor` since each class's constructor only allow you to set one of those.

Comment: Beside be very careful as you created an accessor (getValor) that changes the state of your class. You probably want to return "m_valor + m_valorAdicional" instead of +=, otherwise you would increase m_valorAdicional everytime it's fetched.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `+`, not `+=`. What `+=` does here in this line:

```
return m_valorAdicional +=m_valor;
```

is it adds the value of `m_valor` to `m_valorAdicional`, *changing* the value of `m_valorAdicional`, and then returning this new value. If you don't want to change the values of the variables use `+`.